# Setting the visibility for a linear layout(view group)

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, visibility, isenabled, android-viewgroup

When I set `setVisibility(View.GONE)` or `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` for a linear layout it seems that it does not changes the visibility of the view(saying view group would be more accurate). At various post in SO, it has been suggested that get the count for the particular linear layout and change the visibility of each child one by one. Well that can work but it also increases the time taken to process that piece of code. And when there are various view involve, it will be increase to many folds. Same goes for `setEnabled(true)` or `setEnabled(false)`.

My question is there a alternative for this, as directly changing the visibility is definitely not working? And if not can anybody explain to me why android choose to keep it this way, i.e developer cannot directly change the state(visibility/enabling) of the view group.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Code for what?? Its a generic question related to android. Code snippet has already been marked